# selenium find_elements_by_xpath .get_attribute does not show proper value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I use the following code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'G:\Program Files\chromedriver')
    
    driver.get("https://trader.degiro.nl/login/nl?_ga=2.48166567.1674906184.1604234065-1030449807.1604234065#/login")
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("not actual info")
    
    password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("not actual info")
    
    
    driver.find_element_by_name("loginButtonUniversal").click()
    

    #top nav elements
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/button/span[1]")
    
    for e in elems:
        print(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

To get to this element:

```
<span data-id="totalPortfolio" data-field="total" 
class="uJDZaBS4 " data-positive="true" 
title="22.014,54">€&nbsp;22.014,54</span>
```

But it prints :`€&nbsp;—`

while I want it to print what is actually there: `€&nbsp;22.014,54`

So it turns the value "22.014,54" into "-".

How do I get the original value instead of "-"?

Comment: It would be helpful if u provide the url of the website.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the URL I am visiting is only available after logging in on another URL, should I post the entire process?

Comment: But I can't login with these credentials. It's fine. I will try to figure out a way to print the right value.

Comment: BTW, did u try printing `e.text`?

Comment: I prefer not to share my actual credentials, and yes I did try e.text and gave me a euro sign and again a '-' instead of the actual number.

Comment: Is it ok if my ans uses `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: That would be great, I tried Beautifulsoup first but I didn't even get into the element with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223945/discussion-between-sushil-and-olivier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait after clicking on the login button for the page to load. You can use `time.sleep` in order to do that:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("loginButtonUniversal").click()
time.sleep(3)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/button/span[1]")
```

But using `time.sleep` is not considered as a good practice. Instead I would advice you to use `WebDriverWait`. Here is how you use it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element_by_name("loginButtonUniversal").click()

elems = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/button/span[1]')))
```

Comment: I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: What does `driver.page_source` print for u?

Comment: A whole lot of mostly javascript code, too long for a comment. The dynamic nature of the webpage is why I didn't succeed with beautifulsoup.

Comment: Let's discuss about this in a separate chat room. Click on the link that I have sent u above.